# Debian is not bootable after installation of Open GL libraries

Tags: linux, opengl, debian, steam

I tried to install Steam, but the Open GL Libraries seem to break the system. I'm running Debian Jessie (Kernel 3.16.0.4) with Gnome on a 64bit-Laptop. My Laptop is a HP Pavilion 17, so Windows was preinstalled and I installed Debian later.

lscpu:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            21
Model:                 19
Model name:            AMD A10-5750M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               1400.000
CPU max MHz:           2500.0000
CPU min MHz:           1400.0000
BogoMIPS:              4990.34
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             16K
L1i cache:             64K
L2 cache:              2048K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Installing `libgl1-fglrx-glx-i386` and `steam` (as explained [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Steam#Installation)) returns no errors, but when I restart my computer, I get that grey "Ooops something went wrong!" screen. Then, I have to deinstall the Open GL libs to make my system work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD GPUs have excellent open source driver support. In fact the open source drivers are written in part by AMD engineers and fglrx is on its way out. Instead you should go with just Mesa and the `radeon` and/or `amdgpu` driver modules. A nice side effect of doing so is, that you get "perfect" autoconfiguration and do not have to mess with proprietary kernel modules; things just work.

When you installed Debian it should have preinstalled pretty much every graphics driver that has a free (as in speech) license. And although Debian often is way behind upstream the Mesa/DRI drivers for AMD APUs should be sufficiently new for your system.

Answer (score 1):

Installing packages rarely returns an error (unless there are missing dependencies that cannot be met).

However, what seems a bit odd to me is that the package is named libgl1-fglrx-glx-**i386**, indicating to be supposed to use on a 32 bit system, but your laptop is 64 bit. Maybe you should try the package [libgl1-fglrx-glx](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libgl1-fglrx-glx), that is without the *-i386* suffix, instead. That is just a guess, but maybe it helps.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/Steam#A64-bit_systems_.28amd64.29 **"4. Install 32-bit OpenGL libraries"**